# Morphisms of sheaves v.s. morphisms of presheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ be presheaves on a topological space $X$ and $\alpha$ a morphism of presheaves. Consider the following four statements. I meant here "for all $U$ open in $X$"

1)$\alpha$ is injective on $\mathcal{F}(U)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$ is injective on stalks at $x\in U$
2)$\alpha$ is injective on stalks $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$ is injective on $\mathcal{F}(U)$
3)$\alpha$ is surjective on $\mathcal{F}(U)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$ is surjective on stalks at $x\in U$
4)$\alpha$ is surjective on stalks $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$ is surjective on $\mathcal{F}(U)$

I believe that 1) is true for both sheaves and presheaves, 2) is true for sheaves but false for presheaves, 3) is true for sheaves but not for  presheaves and 4) is true neither sheaves nor presheaves. Can someone confirm/refute please?

P.S. when I say "true for sheaves" I mean "true when $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ are sheaves". Probably I should also think about the cases where one is a sheaf and one isn't but I am confused enough already. Thank you!!

Comment: Do you consider only one open set $U$ ? Or every one ? (The fact that there is a $U$ on both side of the implication let me believe you consider a single open set $U$. In that case they are all false for sheaves and presheaves)

Comment: See what happens when source or target (as needed) sheaf/presheaf, when evaluated at $U$, has only one point in it  - in that case it's too (?) easy to be injective or surjective for $U$... Also, presheaves are fairly floppy -  they are 'only' (contra-variant) functors - no gluing or 'separatedness'. (e.g, restriction maps don't have to be injective.)  For 4, even for sheaves, surjectivity at stalks does NOT mean surjectivity for global sections. Suggestion: take $U$ to be a set with two elements, and try different topologies, with simple (pre-)sheaves (a few elements).

Comment: Why is 2 false for presheaves? If map of presheaves is injective on stalks then map of their sheafification is also injective on stalks. So the map of sheafification is injective  So $\mathcal F ^+ (U) \to \mathcal G^+ (U)$ is injective. Which implies $\mathcal F(U) \to \mathcal G(U)$ is injective?

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal - for presheaves the restriction maps don't have to be injective  - right? take $U$ with two elements, discrete topology, and pre-sheaves with stalks with only one element in them; injectivity is forced on stalks, and you can do what you like at $U$...

Comment: @peterag yes of course, I just wanted the op to precise the quantifiers

Comment: Restrictions need not be injective even for sheaves!

Comment: But what I did, requires the presheaf to be separated. Otherwise the map $\mathcal F \to \mathcal F ^+$ wont be injective.

Comment: @Roland - and what I wrote was (very) weird too: I wanted to conclude $s=t$, not $\alpha(s)=\alpha(t)$...

Comment: Correcting my first comment to @Roland (which I erased [the comment, not Roland] - shame, shame): for sheaves: say $\alpha$ is injective on stalks. If $s\ne t\in \cal F(U)$, then there is a point $p\in U$  for which $s_p \ne t_p$; by the injectivity hypothesis $\alpha(s)_p\ne \alpha(t)_p$. So $\alpha(s)\ne\alpha(t)\in \cal G(U)$, and $\alpha_U$ is injective.

Comment: As @ShubhodipMondal points out (exclaims!), I "misspoke," or, to put it more kindly, was misleading, at the v. least, in my comment above to him. Restriction maps are not necessarily injective - the typical example would be the sheaf of cts functions on $\mathbb R^n$ - e.g. a function may vanish on a non-empty open set without being identically zero (on the whole top. space). However, for sheaves (or separated pre-sheaves) on a top space, $$ \cal F (U) \to \prod_{p\in U} {\cal F}_p$$ is injective. BTW, if we haven't been helpful, let us know...

Comment: @peterag This has all been extremely helpful, thank you very much; The socratic method makes everything better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the OP means "for every open set"...

1,2,3 are true for sheaves. 4 is false for sheaves (and hence presheaves).

Now for presheaves:

1. True. $\alpha$ is injective. So map of their sheafification is injective. Which is therefore exact at stalks. But stalks are same for sheaves or presheaves.
2. False for nonseparated presheaves. Take two point set with discrete topology with only one nonzero global section, rest sections are all zero. In particular the stalks are zero. Now consider the map from $\mathcal F \to \mathcal F$ that sends the nonzero global section to zero. It is a well-defined map. Although it is injective on stalks, it is not injective map of presheaves.

   3.True. $\alpha$ is surjective on the level of sheafification. So surjective on stalks as sheaves and hence has presheaves.

Comment: I think the OP meant for fixed $U$.... @RMary - which is it?

Comment: Its very clear that 1,3 are false even for sheaves in that case. Why not discuss the relatively more interesting case?

Comment: @peterag indeed I did mean for every $U$ but this is not at all clear from my question; will edit now. Thanks for your help everyone!!

Comment: If I get nothing else from stack exchange it has taught me how to ask questions better ;)

Comment: Well, do you consider your question as "not answered"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept, have done so now!