# Characterization: Injective morphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, morphism

Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space and $\varphi : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves over $X$. We call $\varphi$ injective if $\mathcal{K}:=\ker(\varphi) = 0$.

I need to show that this is equivalent to the statement that for all $p \in X$ the morphisms $\varphi_p : \mathcal{F}_p \to \mathcal{G}_p$ induced on the germs are all injective.

My main problems are the following:

- Embarrassingly, I do not get what $\ker(\varphi) = 0$ really means. Let us say we have sheaves over rings. Then the kernel is the zero ring. But does this also mean that for any open set $U \subset X$ the sections $\mathcal{K}(U) = \ker(\varphi_U)$ is also the zero ring?
- I still have no intuition for stalks and germs. We have defined stalks as some set equipped with some weird equivalence relation and germs as their equivalence classes. Neither do I know what injectivity means for the $\varphi_p$ nor how I get the desired conclusions with these.

Could anyone explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For your first question, yes, that's exactly what it means to say that the kernel sheaf is 0.  For your second question, have you studied complex analysis?  The [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) states that if two holomorphic functions agree on an open subset, then they are identical wherever they are both defined.  Thus it makes sense to identify holomorphic functions that agree on some open subset and only consider equivalence classes, aka germs.  This is exactly the equivalence relation defining the stalk of a sheaf.

The stalk of a sheaf is defined as the [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) of the sheaf with its restriction maps:
$$
\mathcal{F}_p = \varinjlim_{U \ni p} \mathcal{F}(U)
$$
taken over all open sets $U \subseteq X$ containing $p$.  Given a morphism $\varphi$ of sheaves, the universal property of the direct limit yields an induced map on the stalks.  More concretely, we can choose a representative $(s,U)$ for a germ $s|_p$.  Since the morphism commutes with the restriction maps, then
\begin{align*}
\varphi_p(s|_p) &= \varphi_p(\operatorname{res}^U_p(s)) = \operatorname{res}^U_p(\varphi_U(s)) \, .
\end{align*}
(Note that the first restriction map is for the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, $\operatorname{res}^U_p: \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}_p$, while the second is for the sheaf $\mathcal{G}$, $\operatorname{res}^U_p: \mathcal{G}(U) \to \mathcal{G}_p$.)
So to compute the action of the stalk map $\varphi_p$ on a germ, we just compute the action of the morphism on a representative for the germ, and then restrict to the stalk.

**EDIT**: Here's a solution to the problem:

Assume $\varphi_p$ is injective for all $p$.  Suppose $U$ is an open set and $s \in \ker(\varphi_U)$, so $\varphi_U(s) = 0$.  Given $p \in U$, then
$$
\varphi_p(s|_p) = \varphi_p(\text{res}^U_p(s)) = \text{res}^U_p(\varphi_U(s)) = \text{res}^U_p(0) = 0 \, .
$$
Since $\varphi_p$ is injective, then $s|_p = 0$, so there exists an open set $V_p \subseteq U$ with $p \in V_p$ such that $\text{res}^U_{V_p}(s) = 0$.  Note that the collection $\{V_p\}_{p \in U}$ forms an open cover of $U$.  Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf and $\text{res}^U_{V_p}(s) = 0$ for all $p \in U$, then $s = 0$ by local determination (the first sheaf axiom).  Thus $\ker(\varphi)(U) = \ker(\varphi_U) = 0$ for all $U$.

Conversely, assume $\ker(\varphi_U) = 0$ for all $U$.  Given $s|_p \in \ker(\varphi_p)$, choose a representative $(s,U)$ for $s|_p$.  Then
$$
0 = \varphi_p(s|_p) = \varphi_p(\text{res}^U_p(s)) = \text{res}^U_p(\varphi_U(s)) \, .
$$
Then there exists an open set $V \subseteq U$ containing $p$ such that
\begin{align*}
0 = \operatorname{res}^U_V(\varphi_U(s)) = \varphi_V(\operatorname{res}^U_V(s)) \, .
\end{align*}
Since $\varphi_V$ is injective, then $\operatorname{res}^U_V(s) = 0$, so
$$
s|_p = \operatorname{res}^U_p(s) = \operatorname{res}^V_p(\operatorname{res}^U_V(s)) = \operatorname{res}^V_p(0) = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Let me know if that answers your question, or if you need another hint for showing the kernel being zero is equivalent to injectivity of the stalk maps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I got one direction: Let $\varphi_p$ be injective for all $p \in X$. Let $U$ be open and $p \in U$. Assume $\varphi_U(s) = \varphi(t)$. Then $res^U_p(\varphi_U (s)) = res^U_p(\varphi_U (t))$ which means $\varphi_p(res^U_p(s)) =  \varphi_p(res^U_p(t))$, so by the injectivity of $\varphi_p$ it is $res^U_p(s) = res^U_p(t)$ and then $s=t$, because $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf. That means $\varphi_U$ is injective and therefore $\ker(\varphi) = 0$ because $U$ was arbitrarily chosen. Can you confirm if this is correct? And some help for the other direction would be nice too.

Comment: You should probably be more explicit about how you are using the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf to conclude $s=t$.  Also, why not just assume that $s \in \ker(\varphi_U)$, so $\varphi_U(s) = 0$?  Since we're talking about kernels, I assume the sheaf is taking values in (at least) abelian groups.  Looks good, otherwise.

Comment: The other direction is actually easier: no sheaf properties or anything, just the definition of a germ being $0$.   Give it a shot, and I'll add an answer to my post a little later.

Comment: To the proof above: $res_p^U(s)=res_p^U(t)$ means that we have the same germ, so $ res_{U,U\cap U}(s) = res_{U,U\cap U}(t)$. But since $U \cap U = U$ and $res_{U,U}(s) = s$ by the (pre-)sheaf axiom (over $\mathcal{F}$, we get $s=t$.

Comment: Question about your hint: Is $\ker(\varphi)_p = \ker(\varphi_p)$? 

If so, then $\ker(\varphi)=0$ implies $\ker(\varphi_p)=0$ which means that $\varphi_p$ is injective. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite: the germs being equal means there is some (smaller) open set $V \subseteq U$ containing $p$ such that $\text{res}^U_V(s) = \text{res}^U_V(t)$.  I think you need to use the local determination axiom of a sheaf.  As for your second question: it's probably true, but you'd still have to prove it.  I'd just try directly: suppose $s|_p \in \ker(\varphi_p)$, pick a representative $(s,U)$,...

Comment: I've added the remaining implication.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Sorry that I have not answered earlier. Thanks for your answer, I think I have understood it. To the first implication: My problem was that in our lecture we have defined $(U,s)$ equivalent to $(V,t)$ if $\operatorname{res}^U_{U \cap V}(s) = \operatorname{res}^V_{U \cap V}(t)$. But I have also noticed that the definition you have given is the common one. But then it is only getting slightly more difficult.

Comment: I also want to give an "alternative" proof for the second implication: Let $\ker (\varphi_U) = 0$ for all $U$. Then $\ker (\varphi)_p = \{ (U,s) | U \text{ open}, p \in U, s \in \ker (\varphi_U)\} = \{ (U,0) | U \text{ open}, p \in U\} = 0$. The first equality is the definition, the second follows from our assumption and the third one means that this set is trivial. This is true because $\operatorname{res}$ is a morphism, meaning $\operatorname{res}^U_V(0) = 0$ for any $V \subset U$. But since $\ker (\varphi)_p = \ker (\varphi_p)$, this means that all $\varphi_p$ are injective.

Comment: I still think there is going to be a problem even using the intersection definition.  If $s|_p  = t|_p$, you can't assume that $s$ and $t$ and defined on the same open set: you have to assume that $(U,s)$ and $(V,t)$ are representatives and $\text{res}^U_{U \cap V}(s) = \text{res}^V_{U \cap V}(t)$.  This implication is not true in general for presheaves (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811036/morphisms-of-sheaves-v-s-morphisms-of-presheaves)), so your proof should require one of the sheaf axioms.

Comment: The other implication seems okay.  Really you're taking the direct limit over the collection you wrote, but the direct limit of $0$ should be $0$.