# Image sheaf isomorphism : another proof? (Exercise 2.1.4 in Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Assume you have a sheaf morphism $f:\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ and consider the sheafification of the presheaf $\textrm{im}(f)$. I want to prove that it's isomorphic to a sub sheaf of $\mathcal{G}$. I basically do this by showing that whenever there is an injective morphism of presheaves $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, the morphism induced on the sheafifications is still injective, hence I can conclude. It's basically Exercise 2.1.4 in Hartshorne. The inclusion $i :\textrm{im}(f)(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{G}(U)$ is injective for all $U$ so the argument applies to my situation. The thing is that the proof is pretty long in this way and I was wondering if there is a more direct way of proving it exploiting the specifics of this context rather than prove it for every injective morphism of presheaves. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you show part (a) in exercise 2.1.4 ? Because then you have a morphism of presheaves $im(f) \to G$ which is injective on each open set $U$, so by (a) you get an injective morphism of sheaves $im(f)^+ \to G^+ \cong G$.

Comment: Yes, but this is the path that I feel makes it too long. Proving part a relies on other exercises as well. Also, it requires proving that the stalks of the presheaf and the stalks of the sheafification are isomorphic. I was wondering if there's a way to exploit the fact that I'm talking about the image sheaf and an inclusion here, rather than a random presheaf and injective presheaf morphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you showed part (a) in exercise 2.1.4, then you are almost done for (b) ! And I don't think there is any easier way that this. It might look too long for you now, but in a few months, I believe that you will actually find this proof rather short !

Indeed, you have a morphism of presheaves 
$$\mathrm{im}(f) \to \mathscr G,$$ 
which is injective on each open set $U$, so by (a) you get an injective morphism of sheaves 
$$\mathrm{im}(f)^+ \to \scr G^+.$$

But $\scr G$ is a sheaf by assumption, so that $\scr G^+ \cong G$. Therefore, the image sheaf $\mathrm{im}(f)^+$ is isomorphic to a subsheaf of $\scr G$

Comment: Well then maybe there's a quicker way to prove part a)? Do you think it's worth it for me to ask another question about it?

Comment: @Dalamar : it is completely normal to find these kind of things a bit difficult at the beginning, while learning sheaf theory. But I really believe that to solve part a), you need to use that sheafification preserves the stalks. This is actually one of the main properties of sheafification ! :-)

Comment: I already proved that :). However after that there's a small problem for me. How can I say that a morphism on the stalks induces a morphism on the whole sheaf and take the final step? Is it just obvious?

Comment: Well, the starting point was a morphism of presheaves, I have to prove that now I can get a morphism between sheafifications after I know that the stalks are the same. Right?

Comment: If $F \to G$ is a morphism of presheaves, then composing with the natural map $G \to G^+$, you get a morphism $F \to G^+$ from a presheaf to a sheaf. By the universal property of sheafification, this morphism factors through a morphism of sheaves $F^+ \to G^+$. Is that answering your comment?

Comment: Yeah but this morphism it factors through will not necessarily be injective. I prove that, proving injectivity on the stalks of $F$. Then I see that the stalks of the sheafification of $F$ are basically the same. But how do I deduce then injectivity of the morphism $F^+ \rightarrow G^+$?

Comment: @Dalamar : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041868) ; if all the induced maps on the stalks are injective, then the morphism of sheaves is injective.

Comment: So it seems that shearification also preserve surjectivity, in the sense that if the morphism of presheaves is surjective for each open sets, then the induced map is also surjective.